# Statsmodels Python Missing Values

Tags: python, pca, missing-data, statsmodels

I'm currenlty working on a project and I have to fill some missing values.
I use Python, and I saw that there is an algorithm which can do missing data imputation.
This algorithm is called Nipals. So, I decided to search a way to use it and I saw that statsmodels.multivariate.pca.PCA could help me.

I have a numpy array named A with n rows and p columns. A has some missing values which are NaN values. I would like to use PCA to fill A. But, there are no examples which can help me to do it.

Can someone help me to fill A using Nipals algorithm ?

Thank you.
N.B. Sorry, I'm a French beginner, it's not easy for me to use english documentations..

Answer (score 4):

I find a way to fill missing values.
Let's assume you have a numpy array named A

```
from statsmodels.multivariate.pca import PCA
pc = PCA(data=A,ncomp=1, missing='fill-em')
A=pc._adjusted_data
```

Enjoy !
You can also use another way to fill missing values : mean, median, k-neighbors, mcmc (Monte Carlo Markov Chain), most frequent value...